# Gitlab Approve Merge Requests

Tags: java, git, merge, gitlab

I can't find in Gitlab the option which is in my opinion common case and thats it to only APPROVE merge requests, but not to trigger the build. I need to separate the process in 2 actions: Approver review and approve the Merge request but the author of the merge request will do the merge, trigger the build and watch if all went good. Currently I see only 1 button in Gitlab which holds both actions : Approving and Merging (which is triggering the build)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking is common. I find it far more common to only approve a merge _once a build is successful_.

Comment: Of course, developer should do the merge by himself and create Merge requests with all the conflicts resolved. In the bitbucket there are 2 buttons for Pull Request (suppose the Pull requests are same than Merge Requests in Gitlab). Ussually the reviewer checks the code and if everything was OK he clicks Approved... And just after that  the Merge is available (ussually we have 2 mandatory reviewers).. I cant find the option in Gitlab

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it is better practice to perform all merges before the merge is accepted.  There is always a chance that a merge can go wrong and it would make it in without getting accepted.

There is a setting in gitlab that will reset all approvals on push.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html#resetting-approvals-on-push

Comment: In Bitbucket there are 2 buttons: Accept and Merge. Merge button is available only when minimal number of reviewers accepted the request. Ussually 2 people check the code, click Approved and the author then click Merge button. If build failed for some reason, everyone knows who is responsible.